# How to use subprocess without Try-Catch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, subprocess

**Can someone answer my question under the only answer? **

I want to use subprocess and be able to read its output, so I used:

```
subprocess.check_output
```

But this wasn't enough for me, I wanted to hide writing to stderror so I added:

```
stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
```

Which wasn't helpful as some commands now have the following output:

```
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['snmpwalk', '-t', '1', '-r', '1', '-v', '3', '-c', 'public', '31.208.215.122', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

How can I fix this without try-catch (I don't want to harm performance as I am calling this code thousands of times)?

Comment: Only you can know which encoding to use for your `snmpwalk` program. `encoding="utf-8"` is a safe choice for UNIX programs, in general.

Comment: `encoding=encodings.utf_8` doesn't work @AKX

Comment: `encoding="utf-8"`.

Answer (score 1):

`subprocess.run` is your friend

`subprocess.check_output` will raise `Exception` upon failure. `.run` won't (unless given `check=True`)

Try something like:

```py
In [1]: import subprocess

In [2]: proc = subprocess.run("echo bla", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

In [3]: print(proc.stdout.decode())
bla
```

Comment: It does, if you use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and then read the return object's stdout. Read the doc

Comment: It's your responsibility to tell `subprocess.run` which encoding to use, or to know how to decode it once you get the raw byte stream from the subprocess. You can use `text=True` and see if the *default* encoding works for you, though.

Comment: Use the `encoding` argument if UTF-8 isn't already the default. Please see the documentation for `subprocess.run`.

Comment: @chepner `encoding=encodings.utf_8` doesn't work

Comment: @chepner I read the documentation this doesn't work...

Comment: @Dan "Doesn't work" will help people understand what the problem is. You **must** explain *exactly* what doesn't work. And why are you doing `encoding=encodings.utf_8`? Nobody told you to do that. They explicitly wrote `encoding="utf-8"`.